# Where does php read the time() from?

Tags: php, datetime, time

Hello as I searched I found that the **Unix Timestamp** is server side provider for `time()` function, from where exactly `php` read the time ?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html

Comment: The OS. How about you ask the X to this Y question? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Sammitch you mean the SERVER OS ?

Comment: Im trying to use time() method to enable disable some subscription packages, I wanted to prevent user manipulate time like local machine time changing and stuff like that

Comment: php gets the time from the OS of the machine it is being executed on. So yes, in the vast majority , some server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP reads the timestamp from the server the php script is being executed on.

> I wanted to prevent user manipulate time like local machine time changing

Your users cannot affect what `time()` returns, because it's the server's timestamp.

Credit to @YVesLeBorg in comments.